# Strava API - changing API Authorisation Callback Domain

Tags: api, strava

This question is specific to the Strava API: https://strava.github.io/api/

I've been working on an app concept app for a while, and have a few hundred users registered with an application that pulls their activity data from the Strava API, however due to reasons beyond my control I'm probably going to have to migrate the app to a new domain.

As a result, I'll need to change the `Authorisation Callback Domain` setting for my application in Strava, and I'm concerned that this may affect the authorisations which I have linked to the current domain - but I dont see anything regarding this in the API docs.

Is anyone aware of whether this would affect existing authorisations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with this question, I can confirm that existing authorisations are retained.

Thanks go to the helpful team on the Strava developers forum:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/strava-api/XyNWmRK1A4Q